# How to properly configure a .gitignore file for a Liferay project using Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, version-control, github, liferay, gitignore

I'm trying to start up a Liferay project using Apache Tomcat (embedded in the Liferay directory).
This project works well and I want to push it on my Github account before developing portlets.
However I don't know how to proceed my .gitignore file.

What kind of files and directories should I ignore ?

- /logs/*
- /tomcat/work/* ?
- /tomcat/temp/* ?
- /tomcat/logs/*

Do you have any idea ? It's seems that Tomcat generates huge quantities of temporary files !

Thanks !

Comment: Why would you push tomcat to your git repository? The repo should contain the sources, not the runtime environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the build tool that you use:

- For Ant, push the plugins sdk, that you can download separately from liferay.com. The result will look like https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins
- For Maven, just push the individual plugin projects

You don't want to push the whole tomcat directory: It does not have the source codes in a meaningful, editable, way. The plugins sdk will be configured so that a build automatically deploys the built plugin into a tomcat dedicated for this environment. You typically do this to your development environment and, at certain times, explicitly to your production environment.

If you want to keep your production environment version-controlled, I'd advise against storing it all under source control, rather do proper scripting of plugin deployment. Some of the reasons are that Liferay explicitly handles hot-deployable plugins, partially by updating a webapp's content (e.g. jsp-hooks will do this) and other plugins are not hot-deployable. You'll have more value knowing which plugins are deployed on your server than having a full server-directory in git. Granted, a backup of everything might be good for quick restore, but in that case even the temporary files (like compiled jsps) might be a good thing to keep available. But that's a different story.